# Obtaining the hash of a file using the stream capabilities of crypto module (ie: without hash.update and hash.digest)

Tags: node.js, hash, stream

The [`crypto`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.18/api/crypto.html) module of node.js (at the time of this writing at least) is not still deemed stable and so the API may change. In fact, the methods that everyone in the internet use to get the hash (md5, sha1, ...) of a file are considered legacy (from the documentation of [`Hash` class](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.18/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash)) (note: emphasis mine):

> Class: Hash
>
> The class for creating hash digests of data.
>
> It is a stream that is both readable and writable. The written data is
>   used to compute the hash. Once the writable side of the stream is
>   ended, use the read() method to get the computed hash digest. The
>   **legacy update and digest methods** are also supported.
>
> Returned by crypto.createHash.

Despite `hash.update` and `hash.digest` being considered legacy, the example shown just above the quoted snippet is using them.

What's the correct way of obtaining hashes without using those legacy methods?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

From the quoted snippet in the question:

> [the Hash class] It is a stream that is both readable and writable. The written data is
>   used to compute the hash. Once the writable side of the stream is
>   ended, use the read() method to get the computed hash digest.

So what you need to hash some text is:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

// change to 'md5' if you want an MD5 hash
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');

// change to 'binary' if you want a binary hash.
hash.setEncoding('hex');

// the text that you want to hash
hash.write('hello world');

// very important! You cannot read from the stream until you have called end()
hash.end();

// and now you get the resulting hash
var sha1sum = hash.read();
```

If you want to get the hash of a file, the best way is create a ReadStream from the file and pipe it into the hash:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');

// the file you want to get the hash    
var fd = fs.createReadStream('/some/file/name.txt');
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
hash.setEncoding('hex');

fd.on('end', function() {
    hash.end();
    console.log(hash.read()); // the desired sha1sum
});

// read all file and pipe it (write it) to the hash object
fd.pipe(hash);
```

Comment: is it possible to get the data content from hash object?

Comment: @sunnycmf what data do you mean? If you mean the original data you were hashing then I don't think so. If you mean the computed hash, then just use `hash.read()`.

Comment: yes i mean orig data, coz want to read the file once and get the data & sha1 hash.

Comment: @sunnycmf you can use pipe twice: file.pipe(hash) and then file.pipe(outputStream)

Comment: Instead of the `fd.on('end')`, it would be better to handle `hash.on('finish')`, which does not require calling `hash.end()`.

Comment: Seems to me the pipe-to-Hash-object method is much more fickle than the old-fashioned `stream.on('data', data => hash.update(data))` and later calling `digest('hex')`. When I did the exact experiment as above but left out `hash.read()` because I wanted to do that on the `finish` event of the write-stream I got nothing, no value. Only when I call `hash.read()` in the `end` event handler as above (or in `finish` suggested by @HermanKan) do I get the hash. No such problems with calling `hash.update(...)` in a `data` event handler, then I can get the hash output anywhere, any time.

Answer (score 48):

An ES6 version returning a Promise for the hash digest:

```
function checksumFile(hashName, path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const hash = crypto.createHash(hashName);
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(path);
    stream.on('error', err => reject(err));
    stream.on('data', chunk => hash.update(chunk));
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(hash.digest('hex')));
  });
}
```

Comment: I like this. Possible improvement here: https://gist.github.com/F1LT3R/2e4347a6609c3d0105afce68cd101561

Answer (score 21):

Short version of Carlos' answer:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var crypto = require('crypto')

fs.createReadStream('/some/file/name.txt').
  pipe(crypto.createHash('sha1').setEncoding('hex')).
  on('finish', function () {
    console.log(this.read()) //the hash
  })
```

Answer (score 16):

Further polish, ECMAScript 2015

`hash.js`:

```js
'use strict';

function checksumFile(algorithm, path) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let fs = require('fs');
    let crypto = require('crypto');

    let hash = crypto.createHash(algorithm).setEncoding('hex');
    fs.createReadStream(path)
      .once('error', reject)
      .pipe(hash)
      .once('end', function () {
        resolve(hash.read());
      });
  });
}

checksumFile('sha1', process.argv[2]).then(function (hash) {
  console.log('hash:', hash);
});
```

```bash
node hash.js hash.js
hash: 9c92ec7acf75f943aac66ca17427a4f038b059da
```

Works at least as early as v10.x:

```bash
node --version
v10.24.1
```

Comment: Didn't work for me - needed to add `this.end()` before `this.read()`.

Comment: probably you mean `.once('end', ...`

Answer (score 6):

I use Node module hasha successfully, the code becomes very clean and short. It returns a promise, so you can use it with await:

```
const hasha = require('hasha');

const fileHash = await hasha.fromFile(yourFilePath, {algorithm: 'md5'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fd = fs.createReadStream('data.txt');
var hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
hash.setEncoding('hex');
fd.pipe(hash);
hash.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('# ',data);
});
```

Comment: You should explain your code so that others can understand it