# How to output multiple encodings of a file hash without relying on deprecated node.js features

Tags: node.js, hash, stream

The goal is to output both the base64 and hex encodings of a file's MD5 hash without relying on deprecated node.js features. This means using `Hash.read()` instead of `Hash.digest()`, and using `Buffer` instances instead of `"binary"`-encoded strings. From the docs:

> Once the writable side of the [Hash] stream is ended, use the read() method to get the
>   computed hash digest. *The **legacy** update and digest methods are also supported.*

and

> [The "binary"] encoding method *is **deprecated** and should be avoided* in favor of Buffer objects
>   where possible. This encoding will be removed in future versions of Node.

So far, I cannot see how computing multiple hash encodings is possible in 0.10.22 without using these deprecated features. (Technically, hash.digest() is not deprecated, but I'm wary to use anything labeled legacy).

The best I've found still relies on `"binary"`-encoded strings:

```
var fs = require("fs"), crypto = require("crypto");

var input = fs.createReadStream("test.txt");
var hash = crypto.createHash("md5");

hash.setEncoding("binary");

input.pipe(hash).on("finish", function() {
    var buffer = new Buffer(hash.read(), "binary");
    console.log(buffer.toString("hex"));
    console.log(buffer.toString("base64"));
});
```

If the call to `hash.setEncoding` is removed, then the subsequent `hash.read()` method returns null. Perhaps this is a bug? Kinda expected an instance of Buffer...

Any ideas on how to avoid the above deprecated features?

(For reference, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658612/obtaining-the-hash-of-a-file-using-the-stream-capabilities-of-crypto-module-ie) covers how to compute one hash encoding, not multiple encodings.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `"finish"` event is triggered when the `input` has finished piping to the `hash` object, not when the hash is ready to be read. Setting the encoding must change the path that is followed somehow to make 'finish' fire late enough that your example works.

The `'readable'` event will trigger when there is data to be read, and then you can read from `hash` to accumulate all of the hash chunks to make a single buffer.

You can use a module like [accum](https://npmjs.org/package/accum) or you can bind the listeners yourself:

```
var input = fs.createReadStream("test.txt");
var hash = input.pipe(crypto.createHash("md5"));

var chunks = [];
hash.on('readable', function() {
    var chunk;
    while ((chunk = hash.read()) !== null){
        chunks.push(chunk);
    }
});
hash.on('end', function(){
    var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);

    console.log(buffer.toString("hex"));
    console.log(buffer.toString("base64"));
});
```