# How to use ES8 async/await with streams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/18658613/779159 is an example of how to calculate the md5 of a file using the built-in crypto library and streams.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');

// the file you want to get the hash    
var fd = fs.createReadStream('/some/file/name.txt');
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
hash.setEncoding('hex');

fd.on('end', function() {
    hash.end();
    console.log(hash.read()); // the desired sha1sum
});

// read all file and pipe it (write it) to the hash object
fd.pipe(hash);
```

But is it possible to convert this to using ES8 async/await instead of using the callback as seen above, but while still keeping the efficiency of using streams?

Comment: `async/await` is nothing but syntax-level support for promises. If you can put this code inside a promise, then you are done.

Comment: Node.js 10.x supports using `for-await-of` to read streams (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/stream.html#stream_streams_compatibility_with_async_generators_and_async_iterators) but I think it's not the right concept for your question here. Leaving it as a note for others who might come here facing a situation where it would help.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

The `await` keyword only works on promises, not on streams. There are ideas to make an extra stream-like data type that would get its own syntax, <s>but those are highly experimental if at all and I won't go into details</s>.

Anyway, your callback is only waiting for the end of the stream, which is a perfect fit for a promise. You'd just have to wrap the stream:

```
var fd = fs.createReadStream('/some/file/name.txt');
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
hash.setEncoding('hex');
// read all file and pipe it (write it) to the hash object
fd.pipe(hash);

var end = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    hash.on('end', () => resolve(hash.read()));
    fd.on('error', reject); // or something like that. might need to close `hash`
});
```

There also exists a helper function to do just that in more recent versions of nodejs - [`pipeline` from the stream/promises module](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streams-promises-api):

```
import { pipeline } from 'node:stream/promises';
const fd = fs.createReadStream('/some/file/name.txt');
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
hash.setEncoding('hex');

// read all file and pipe it (write it) to the hash object
const end = pipeline(fd, hash);
```

Now you can await that promise:

```
(async function() {
    let sha1sum = await end;
    console.log(sha1sum);
}());
```

Comment: Congratulations! Now it is not a right answer, now you can use async cycle with streams http://2ality.com/2018/04/async-iter-nodejs.html. Unfortunately, it is an experimental feature now.

Comment: @MiF So you mean the answer is wrong, because it's not "highly experimental" but just "experimental"? :-D

Comment: JS move to use promises and async/await in all async cases. It is too strange, that this fiature wasnt released in production. I think, it is a good sintacsys now and will not changed.

Comment: Why are you waiting for the ReadStream to `end`? Wouldn't the Promise resolve before the hash function has a chance to perform on the data? Or, at the very least, wouldn't it create a race condition? I would assume you would want to store the value of `fd.pipe(hash)` in a variable and listen for the `finish` event as that would signal that the WriteableStream (hashing) has completed.

Comment: @adam-beck Sounds like you're right. Why I did it this way? Because OP did that in their question as well. Feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: Well I did some digging. And now I'm not so sure: nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_events_finish_and_end

Comment: this answer seems a bit old school now. for example, line 1 "async/await only works with promises, not with streams." not true any more. use pipeline from `node:stream/promises`, or for-await while consuming.

Comment: @rosmcmahon I've clarified - I would say it is still true that you cannot `await` a stream itself.

Comment: Friggin love it!

Answer (score 89):

If you are using node version >= v10.0.0 then you can use [stream.pipeline](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback) and [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const util = require('util');
const stream = require('stream');

const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);

const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
hash.setEncoding('hex');

async function run() {
  await pipeline(
    fs.createReadStream('/some/file/name.txt'),
    hash
  );
  console.log('Pipeline succeeded');
}

run().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Should unpipe be called somewhere also?

Comment: I had to dig for hours until I've found this answer. Why is this not included in the Node Streams docs as an example...?

Comment: But it is in the docs. https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback

Comment: note that there's an issue with pipeline stream flushing in node < 15.5.1
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/34274

Answer (score 76):

Node V15 now has a promisfiy pipeline in [stream/promises](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback).
This is the cleanest and most official way.

```
const { pipeline } = require('stream/promises');

async function run() {
  await pipeline(
    fs.createReadStream('archive.tar'),
    zlib.createGzip(),
    fs.createWriteStream('archive.tar.gz')
  );
  console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
}

run().catch(console.error);
```

We all should appreciate how much works it's done here:

- Capture errors in all the streams.
- Destroy unfinished streams when error is raised.
- Only return when the last writable stream is **finished**.

This pipe thing is one of the most powerful feature Node.JS has.  Making it fully async is not easy.  Now we have it.

Answer (score 21):

2021 Update:

New example from Node documentation:

```
async function print(readable) {
  readable.setEncoding('utf8');
  let data = '';
  for await (const chunk of readable) {
    data += chunk;
  }
  console.log(data);
}
```

see https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_symbol_asynciterator

Answer (score 20):

Something like this works:

```
for (var res of fetchResponses){ //node-fetch package responses
    const dest = fs.createWriteStream(filePath,{flags:'a'});
    totalBytes += Number(res.headers.get('content-length'));
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        res.body.pipe(dest);
        res.body.on("error", (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
        dest.on("finish", function() {
            resolve();
        });
    });         
}
```

Comment: Great explanation, I used this promise to wrap an https request I am making using NodeJS built in https module. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I believe it will be helpful for someone:

```
async function readFile(filename) {
    let records = []
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fs.createReadStream(filename)
            .on("data", (data) => {
                records.push(data);
            })
            .on("end", () => {
                resolve(records)
            });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would comment, but don't have enough reputation.

A WORD OF CAUTION:
If you have an application that is passing streams around AND doing async/await, be VERY CAREFUL to connect ALL pipes before you await. You can end up with streams not containing what you thought they did. Here's the minimal example

```
const { PassThrough } = require('stream');

async function main() {
    const initialStream = new PassThrough();

    const otherStream = new PassThrough();
    const data = [];
    otherStream.on('data', dat => data.push(dat));
    const resultOtherStreamPromise = new Promise(resolve => otherStream.on('end', () => { resolve(Buffer.concat(data)) }));

    const yetAnotherStream = new PassThrough();
    const data2 = [];
    yetAnotherStream.on('data', dat => data2.push(dat));
    const resultYetAnotherStreamPromise = new Promise(resolve => yetAnotherStream.on('end', () => { resolve(Buffer.concat(data2)) }));

    initialStream.pipe(otherStream);
    initialStream.write('some ');

    await Promise.resolve(); // Completely unrelated await

    initialStream.pipe(yetAnotherStream);
    initialStream.end('data');
    const [resultOtherStream, resultYetAnotherStream] = await Promise.all([
        resultOtherStreamPromise,
        resultYetAnotherStreamPromise,
    ]);

    console.log('other stream:', resultOtherStream.toString()); // other stream: some data
    console.log('yet another stream:', resultYetAnotherStream.toString()); // yet another stream: data
}
main();
```