# Wait for streams to completely update a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to obtain some data from multiple streams, and appending them to a particular variable. The code is as follows.

```
const fs = require('fs');
data = [];
chunks = {"stream1": { "start": "10", "end": "20"}, "stream2": { "start": "20", "end": "30"}};
for(let key in chunks) {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt', {start: parseInt(chunks[key].start), end: parseInt(chunks[key].end)});
    stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data.push(chunk.toString());
    }
}
console.log(data);
```

But, what data outputs is an empty array `[]`. Someone please help me, to get the data in the `data` variable and then display it, not before that.

I thought of creating an event that is emitted when the length of the array reaches a particular number, but it just seemed weird.

Comment: You need to await for the stream to complete https://stackoverflow.com/a/33599789/9715163

Comment: I had a look at it, but didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined with [How to use ES8 async/await with streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599688/how-to-use-es8-async-await-with-streams/33599789#33599789) and a bit "modernized" you'll want something like this.

```js
async function getData() {
  const out = [];
  const chunks = { stream1: { start: '10', end: '20' }, stream2: { start: '20', end: '30' } };
  for (const key in chunks) {
    for await (const chunk of fs.createReadStream('file.txt', {
      start: parseInt(chunks[key].start),
      end: parseInt(chunks[key].end),
    })) {
      out.push(chunk.toString());
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```