# Working with Node.js streams without callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-streams

To send a PDF file from a Node.js server to a client I use the following code:

```js
const pdf = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

const chunks = [];

pdf.on("data", (chunk) => {
    chunks.push(chunk);
});

pdf.on("end", () => {
    const pdfBuffered = `data:application/pdf;base64, ${Buffer.concat(chunks).toString("base64")}`;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    res.setHeader("Content-Length", pdfBuffered.length);
    res.send(pdfBuffered);
});

pdf.end();
```

Everything is working correctly, the only issue is that the stream here is using callback-approach rather then `async`/`await`.

I've found a [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65938887):

```js
const { pipeline } = require("stream/promises");

async function run() {
    await pipeline(
        fs.createReadStream('archive.tar'),
        zlib.createGzip(),
        fs.createWriteStream('archive.tar.gz')
    );

    console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
}

run().catch(console.error);
```

But I can't figure out how to adopt the initial code to the one with `stream/promises`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually wrap your PDF code in a promise like this and then use it as a function that returns a promise:

```
function sendPDF(docDefinition) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const pdf = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

        const chunks = [];

        pdf.on("data", (chunk) => {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        pdf.on("end", () => {
            const pdfBuffered =
                `data:application/pdf;base64, ${Buffer.concat(chunks).toString("base64")}`;
            resolve(pdfBuffered);
        });

        pdf.on("error", reject);

        pdf.end();
    });
}

sendPDF(docDefinition).then(pdfBuffer => {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    res.setHeader("Content-Length", pdfBuffer.length);
    res.send(pdfBuffer);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
});
```

Because there are many `data` events, you can't promisify just the data portion.  You will still have to listen for each `data` event and collect the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can only convert a callback-API to `async`/`await` if the callback is intended to only be executed once.

The one you found online works, because you're just waiting for the whole stream to finish before the callback runs once. What you've got is callbacks that execute multiple times, on every incoming chunk of data.

There are other resources you can look at to make streams nicer to consume, like [RXJS](https://rxjs.dev/), or [this](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable) upcoming ECMAScript proposal to add observables to the language. Both of these are designed to handle the scenario when a callback can execute multiple times — something that `async`/`await` can not do.

Comment: Thanks for the references, I'll check it!