# JavaScript NodeJS How to use stream/promises with async functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I have a JS async function in Node. Say, it downloads a file from a URL and does something with it, eg. unzip it. I wrote it like this, it works, but `eslint` showed me there is a thick code smell: `error  Promise executor functions should not be async no-async-promise-executor`. `Async` was required because of `await fetch` in body function.

I am not skilled enough with `streams` nor `async/await` to correct it by myself. I would like to get rid of the Promise and fully use `async/await`. The module `stream/promises` seems the way to go from Node-15 on as commented here [how-to-use-es8-async-await-with-streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599688/how-to-use-es8-async-await-with-streams#answer-65938887). How to use `await pipeline(...)` in this context? Maybe there's a better and shorter way?

Here's the function:

```js
function doSomething(url) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(someFile, {
        autoClose: true,
        flags: 'w',
      });

      const res = await fetch(url);
      const body = res.body;
      body
        .pipe(fileWriteStream)
        .on('error', (err) => {
          reject(err);
        })
        .on('finish', async () => {
          await doWhatever();
          resolve('DONE');
        });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: not sure if this is your issue, but the `async function doSomething` serves no purpose for you...it should just be `function doSomething` since you return a `Promise`

Comment: Well, yes, I extracted the function from some larger code, but it's indeed off topic here.  I am removing it from my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `fs/promises` in NodeJS and trim your code down to the following:

```js
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises'

async function doSomething(url) {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    if (!res.ok) throw new Error('Response not ok');
    await writeFile(someFile, res.body, { encoding: 'utf-8'})
    await doWhatever();
    return 'DONE';
  });
}
```

Comment: You use `fetch(url).then` which avoids using `async (resolve, reject) =>...`, but my question is about to only use `async/await`  with `await fetch(url)` in function body? or as an alternative, use  `stream/promises` `pipeline` function, if possible ?

Comment: Apologies. I've updated my answer. Streams are a bit much for the simple thing you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know `writeFile`. The code is much cleaner! is it also feasible with `pipeline` and `createWriteStream`, something like `pipeline( ~fetch as a stream~, fs.createWriteStream) `?

Comment: I'm using named imports - `import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises';`. You could also do `import fs from 'fs/promises';` and you get most of the file system API in promises form. You can then await most file system operations: `await fs.writeFile(...);`. Also, if this solved your problem, it's polite to accept the answer so others know that it worked. Cheers!

Comment: Of course I will! Thanks! still digesting the answers so far.

Comment: Sorry  I was mistaken by `writeFile` which comes from  `fs/promises`, not `stream/promises` ! Can I use `stream/promises` function, namely `pipeline` and `finished` in your reworked example? That's the definitive answer I am at.

Comment: Bergi shows how to use `pipeline` in their answer, though I think it's unnecessary for this situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237396/discussion-between-jgran-and-ryan-wheale).

Answer (score 3):

You could simply perform the `await` before getting to the executor:

```
async function doSomething(url) {
  
  const fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(someFile, { autoClose: true, flags: 'w' });
  
  let { body } = await fetch(url);
  
  body.pipe(fileWriteStream);
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    body.on('error', reject);
    body.on('finish', resolve);
  });
  
};
```

My advice in general is to remove as much code from within your promise executors as possible. In this case the Promise is only necessary to capture resolution/rejection.

Note that I've also removed `doWhatever` from within `doSomething` - this makes `doSomething` much more robust. You can simply do:

```
doSomething('http://example.com').then(doWhatever);
```

Lastly I recommend you set `someFile` as a parameter of `doSomething` instead of referencing it from some broader context!

Comment: Thanks. Your code is indeed very clean and upside down of my poor one. Sorry for `someFile` in the wrong place, a mistake in the hard job of writing a good snippet.

Comment: Very tidy and clean solution, yes, but I was scratching my head wondering why it did not work at first. Then I found the crucial issue: the `reject` and `resolve` parameters in the callback signature are reversed. In other words, the return statement should start out `return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {`.

Comment: @MichaelSorens Woops, good catch! Fixed!

Answer (score 3):

To use the `pipeline` function you're looking for, it would be

```
const { pipeline } = require('stream/promises');

async function doSomething(url) {
  const fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(someFile, {
    autoClose: true,
    flags: 'w',
  });

  const res = await fetch(url);
  await pipeline(res.body, fileWriteStream);
  await doWhatever();
  return 'DONE';
}
```