# How to get data out of a stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I would have expected that I got all the CSV data in the array, but for some reason I don't get anything.

Can someone explain why `a` is empty at the end?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { parse } = require('csv-parse');

let a = [];

fs.createReadStream('./example.csv')
   .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ';', from_line: 2 }))
   .on('data', function (row) {
      a.push(row);
   })
   .on('end', function () {
      console.log('finished');
   })
   .on('error', function (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
   });

console.log(a);
```

Comment: This is because `a` is logged **before** the stream is read. Move the log inside the `end` callback.

Comment: If I replace `.push(row);` with `console.log(row)` then I see the data. Can you show what you mean by moving the log to `end`?

Comment: Just replace `console.log('finished')` with `console.log(a)`. Because streams are async, in your current code `console.log(a)` is executed either before the stream is read or while the stream is read. the `end` stream event should be raised once all the data has been read and the stream has been closed, hence, at such a point, `a` will be filled. If you don't feel comfortable with the callback approach, you might want to take a look at stream/promise, check this question for further informations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65938887/2275797 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a` is `undefined` because the code is executed asynchronously. The `on()` function is called after your `console.log(a)` is executed.

You can read the value of `a` inside the `data` event or the `end` event:

```js
fs.createReadStream('./example.csv')
   .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ';', from_line: 2 }))
   .on('data', function (row) {
      a.push(row);
      console.log(a) // <------- here
   })
   .on('end', function () {
      console.log('finished');
      console.log(a) // <------- here
   })
   .on('error', function (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
   });
```

One solution may be to use a `Promise`

```js
const readCSVData = async () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
let a = []
fs.createReadStream('./example.csv')
   .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ';', from_line: 2 }))
   .on('data', function (row) {
      a.push(row);
   })
   .on('end', function () {
      // return the a value 
      resolve(a) 
   })
   .on('error', function (error) {
      reject(error)
   });
})

// ..... 

const foo = async () => {
  const data = await readCSVData()
  console.log(data)
}

// or
readCSVData().then(a => console.log(a))
```

Comment: If I add `foo()` then it gives `TypeError: readCSVData is not a function`.

Comment: I edited the answer, it should go now.

Comment: You should use the stream/promise api instead of manually promisifying a stream.

Answer (score 2):

createReadStream() runs parallel. So after calling this function, the program continues and the next process is your console.log(a).
Thats the idea behind streams because the program can continue running while the big file is read out.

The code inside the .on() functions is called later. Thats why they are called "callbacks".

So you are logging the result before any data is read...

Comment: What I don't understand is that I can see the data if I replace `a.push(row)` with `console.log(row)`.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting okay. As I said the .on() functions are called by the createReadStream(). So the file needs to be opened etc. That takes a while. If the data is available your function inside .on('data'... is called. Thats one point. If you look at your log, you should see that console.log(a); is executed before console.log(row); That is because createReadStream() is async. It creates a new thread. So the program runs parallel. After calling createReadStream() it directly continues processing. So console.log(a); is executed. After opening the file etc. data is available and gets logged.

Answer (score 2):

As explained before the headstream runs in the background. You can wrap the stream in a promise to get the result. Here is one possible solution:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { parse } = require('csv-parse');

const readFile = async () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let a = [];
    fs.createReadStream('./example.csv')
        .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ';', from_line: 2 }))
        .on('data', function (row) {
            a.push(row);
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            resolve(a);
        })
        .on('error', function (error) {
            reject(error)
        });
});

readFile().then(data => console.log(data))
```