# How to get sender addresses of all mails of inbox of Gmail? (But optimized way)

Tags: google-apps-script, optimization, gmail, gmail-api

I know with Apps Script I can use the functions getInboxThreads() and getMessages() but they basically fetch the entire messages and then I can read the sender address of each message. This is ok if I have less than 5000 mails, but I have 100K mails, and it takes **many hours** (with [batch operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216693/count-number-of-gmail-emails-per-sender), since Google has API call daily limits) to fetch all messages with  getInboxThreads and getMessages functions.

I just want to get the index, I mean, only sender addresses, nothing more. Is there any faster (more optimized) way to do it using Apps Script? or maybe there is some other way to do it?

If not with Apps Script, then maybe with Gmail API? Or maybe with Google Takeout MBOX file? How can I extract sender addresses of all messages from MBOX file? Also note that 100K mails MBOX file will be probably more than 10 GB size and may be problematic for desktop apps to open it.

Thanks.

I tried reading Apps Script docs, but found no optimized way.

Answer (score 0):

### Google Apps Script: Get Email Senders in Gmail's Inbox

You may try this sample script, which gets the email senders from your Gmail inbox. This includes the ones inside a thread, as your post suggested that you wanted to `get sender addresses of all mails of inbox of Gmail`.

```
const myFunction = () => {
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  threads.forEach(thread => {
    var messages = thread.getMessages();
    messages.forEach(email => {
      var emailSenders = email.getFrom();
      console.log(emailSenders);
    });
  });
}
```

> The script may take longer to run as it would depend on the number of items to check in the inbox.

#### OUTPUT

[image]

#### REFERENCES

- [Class GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)
- [Class GmailThread](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread)
- [Class GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message)

Comment: Please note that I won't be able to replicate the number of emails that you have since you mentioned that you have `100K mails`. However, I tried it on email accounts that have 4k and 7k emails, and the code took less than a minute to complete. Also, this answer is purely to try and help you with the concern that you have to get the email senders from Gmail's inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Online method (Apps Script and/or Gmail API method) seems kinda unable and/or unstable to deal with 100K+ mailbox, becuase Google has daily limitations of api calls, and even if it did not have daily limits, it is very slow, when I tried it, it takes several minutes to fetch 1000 mails, so, for 100K, it will take 3-4-5 hours, maybe more.

So, well, I decided to look into the offline solution, with Google Takeout mbox file. I tried this method:

[Node.js - optimal way to handle await inside the stream data listener (mbox email parsing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77176245/node-js-optimal-way-to-handle-await-inside-the-stream-data-listener-mbox-emai)

And it seems working fine, it takes only 5-10 seconds to analyze 1000 mails. So, for 100K, it will take less than 10-20 minutes.