# hash in nodejs is different from hash in terminal

Tags: node.js, hash, md5

I would like to get the md5 hash of a file in nodejs, but the hash i'm getting is different from the hash i can get directly from the terminal.

In nodejs, I'm doing this (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658612/obtaining-the-hash-of-a-file-using-the-stream-capabilities-of-crypto-module-ie))

```
var fd = fs.createReadStream('path/to/my/file');
var hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
hash.setEncoding('hex');

fd.on('end', function() {
    hash.end();
    console.log(hash.read()); // the desired sha1sum
});

fd.pipe(hash);
```

and the output is `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`

And in my terminal I do:

`md5sum path/to/my/file`

and the ouput is `f6ef86836065f2370ebd9b1caadce3b4`

Do you have any idea about why ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is my code:

```
//Download file
var firmware = fs.createWriteStream(desiredFirmwareProperties.fwName);
var r = https.get(desiredFirmwareProperties.fwURI, function(response) {
    response.pipe(firmware);
});

//Checksum
var fd = fs.createReadStream(desiredFirmwareProperties.fwName);
var hash = crypto.createHash(desiredFirmwareProperties.fwChecksumAlgo);     
hash.setEncoding('hex');
fd.on('end', function() {
    hash.end();
    console.log(desiredFirmwareProperties.fwChecksum);
    console.log(hash.read());
});
fd.pipe(hash);
```

Comment: Your code works.I checked and replicated

Comment: Yes I know it's working, but why the hash is different from the one i can get in my terminal ?

Comment: The hash is same too .I checked

Comment: Ok weird.. It's definitely not the same for me

Comment: see the answer.I just posted

Comment: a problem from content differ in function of your environment ?

Comment: @Nicolas what do you mean ?

Comment: are you sure the two files you hash (via shell and via node) have the same content ? it should of course, but the experience show me some error like this refer a different file with same name, in different location, or different server, ...

Comment: @iAmoric after a quick search on google about d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e it appear that it is an empty string, add `fd.on('error', e => console.log(e))`

Comment: @Nicolas Ok thanks for pointing that out to me. I will re-check my code

Comment: I added my code, could you please check what is wrong ? Thanks

Comment: @iAmoric you should check each step until the file open: url is correct, ssl certificate is not rejected, server respond a 200 status code, content downloaded length > 0

Comment: The file is downloaded correctly, I checked it. The problem comes from the second part (checksum)

Answer (score 0):

I got it, it's an asynchronous procedure, you tried to read the file before the download finished

place the checksum procedure in 'close' event:

```
firmware.on('close', () => {
  <checksum here>
})
```

Comment: I don't think, i use `async.waterfall` to avoid this situation

Comment: can you share the bind callback to let async.waterfall execute the next step ?

Comment: Ok I get it, the callback was indeed not placed in the right place. Solved